# select from object stream given array of keys

Tags: json, key, jq

How can I select in jq some fields from an array of keys? Not constants, but a list of keys:

```
| $fields = ["name", "url"]
| . [$fields]
```

Comment: people may not know what jq is: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

a link is nice

Comment: please, if you can provide a sample input and a sample expected output, it would help to answer your question

Comment: @Vetras - The jq tag is sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it will be this :

```
$ jq --argjson paths '[["foo"],["foo","bar"]]' 'getpath($paths[])' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want fields from the top level object from an array, you could just index normally:

```
$ jq --arg fields 'name,url' '.[$fields | split(",")[]]' input.json
```

And in general, if you need values at arbitrary paths, it'd be better to input as paths:

```
$ jq --argjson paths '[["foo"],["foo","bar"]]' 'getpath($paths[])' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

For just the values, you could use `getpath`:

```
$ echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' |
  jq --argjson keys '["a","c"]' '$keys[] as $key | getpath([$key])'
1
3
```

Answer (score -1):

(without a sample input/output this is the best I can guess)

maybe this:

```
<<input>> | jq '.[] | {foo: .name, bar: .url}'
```

any of this helps? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/